# yadcf externally triggered filters 'shut off' the actual filtering

Tags: datatables, filtering, yadcf

I am trying to set my yadcf filters up so they can be triggered from a call (link) from another page. I have an angular single page application that has three tabs on it. If a user clicks a link on lets say the first tab, they will go to another tab (separate table) that contains detailed information relevant to the link they click. (e.g. They are on a row in a table that deals with Apple Mac Pro computers. They see that there are 20 skus currently in the system. They click the number 20 and they go to a lower tab (different table) that contains all the information for those skus). There is no server call in the middle. All the data is loaded in all the tables when the application loads up. So, they are simply clicking a link that applies a filter to the detail table.

yadcf can do this through externally_triggered filters. However, when I set 'externally_triggered': true, it stops the actual filters from working on the details table. (In other words, I can no longer go to that table and manually adjust the filters.)

Does anyone know a way around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the externally_triggered: true switch does not need to be turned on to use yadcf.exFilterColumn() method. I do not understand when it does need to be turned on, but I am able to call the exFilterColumn method and pass it the options needed to 'prefilter' the table while still retaining the ability to filter the table manually.

Answer (score 0):

`externally_triggered` and `yadcf.exFilterColumn` are not related in any way, indeed when `yadcf.exFilterColumn` is used filters behave a bit differently - they are not filtering on change/keyup/etc , but rather only when the `uadcf.exFilterExternallyTriggered` function is called (its on purpose and all is explained in the docs)

Here is the relevant text from the docs of the *externally_triggered*, here it is:

```
* externally_triggered
      Required:           false
      Type:               boolean
      Default value:      false
      Description:        Filters will filter only when yadcf.exFilterExternallyTriggered(table_arg) is called
      Special notes:      Useful when you want to build some form with filters and you want to trigger the filter when that form
                          "submit" button is clicked (instead of filtering per filter input change)
```

[Here is the showcase page](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_source_externally_triggered.html)